# How to return LocalDateTime from REST controller endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, controller

**I'm writing a REST controller in Spring- java, and one of my endpoints should return a `LocalDateTime` variable.**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/lastDateTimeOfReset")
LocalDateTime fetchLastDateTimeOfReset() {
   return mongoManagerService.fetchLastDateTimeOfReset();
}
```

This is the client request:

```
ResponseEntity<LocalDateTime> lastDateEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, LocalDateTime.class);
```

I get the following excepation on my client side:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: 
Error while extracting response for type [class java.time.LocalDateTime] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
JSON parse error: Expected array or string.; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Expected array or string.
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

I checked the return value on debug mode and it is a valid LocalDateTime.
**Why is this exception thrown and how to overcome it?**

Comment: Can you try with below client call.  ResponseEntity<LocalDateTime> lastDateEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
In general- I should've added this configuration to my app:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig {    
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class MessageConvertersConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper()));
        }

        @Bean
        public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
            DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss");
            SimpleModule localDateModule = new SimpleModule();
            localDateModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(dateTimeFormatter));
            localDateModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(dateTimeFormatter));

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.registerModules(localDateModule);

            return mapper;
        }
    }
}
```

*** IMPORTANT!!! - In Tests add this to your rest template: ***

```
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(Collections.singletonList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String to overcome this issue.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/lastDateTimeOfReset")
String fetchLastDateTimeOfReset() {
   return (mongoManagerService.fetchLastDateTimeOfReset()).toString();
}
```

Client Request:

```
ResponseEntity<String> lastDateEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

Comment: as a last resort I will do that, but wanted to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

You need to check **return type** of *mongoManagerService.fetchLastDateTimeOfReset();*

Or Test your application with below sample code

**Service**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/lastDateTimeOfReset")
    LocalDateTime fetchLastDateTimeOfReset() {
       return LocalDateTime.now();
    }
```

**Client**

```
RestTemplate rs = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<LocalDateTime> lastDateEntity = rs.getForEntity(new URI("http://localhost:8089/lastDateTimeOfReset"), LocalDateTime.class);
System.out.println(lastDateEntity);
```

**Output**

> <200,2020-02-19T15:00:51.603220,[Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Date:"Wed, 19 Feb 2020 09:30:51 GMT"]>

Comment: Whats exception?

Comment: same as what I posted. thing is, when I use postman it works just fine. so I'm assuming something with my spring test isn't configured properly

Comment: How you did you created object of RestTemplate. Verify If there is any bean define for same along with configurations

Comment: replace **getForEntity** to **getForObject**